# Get optimize list of language in Android

Tags: android, locale

I want to get list of language in Android and I use this function to get it but it give me a lot of value with the same language but different country (but it so many like we have more than 20 English with different country, it's not neccessary).

```
private ArrayList<ObjSelection> getLanguages() {
        Locale[] locale = Locale.getAvailableLocales();// 271 values
        ArrayList<ObjSelection> countries = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Locale loc : locale) {
            String country = loc.getDisplayCountry();
            String language = loc.getDisplayLanguage();
            if (country.length() > 0 && !countries.contains(country)) {
                countries.add(new ObjSelection(language, country, false));
            }
        }
        Collections.sort(countries, new Comparator<ObjSelection>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(ObjSelection lhs, ObjSelection rhs) {
                return lhs.item.compareToIgnoreCase(rhs.item);
            }
        });
        return countries;//216 values
    }
```

Show could any one tell me any way to optimize that list?

Comment: You can just check the language string that you already got that language. But I guess you want to leave something like, AmericanEnglish and BritishEnglish and skip the others. So the only way to create that list manually.